# intellij - spring is not being recognized (Unmapped Spring configuration)

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA and all plugins for Spring are activated,
but when I load my Maven project I have the following error:

> Spring Configuration Check
>   Unmapped Spring configuration files found.
>   Please configure/setup Spring facet for modules

Any ideas what prevented it from being configured automatically?

Comment: I want to add some more info to the question. When this popup comes, it means Intellij is "suspecting" that you have some files in your module(s) of the opened project which should ideally be SPRING BEANS and you can PROVIDE the spring "contexts" to them and confirm Intellij that that they are indeed spring beans in your project so next time when you play with these files, spring bean code specific suggestions/code editing help can be provided by Intellij. No harm if you ignore this popup, but if you are using a rich IDE, why to miss awesomeness.

Answer (score 108):

You need to do the following:

1. Go to the project structure dialog (either by clicking the warning or through file=>project structure
2. select the **modules** item in the left hand list
3. go through and **right click** on the modules with missing files and select **Add=>Spring**
4. in the new tab **click the + button**
5. you should now see a list of the xml files.  Check the boxes next to them

It's not entirely clear to me what this achieves apart from getting rid of the warnings! If anyone could shed any light on that it'd be good.

Comment: Once the configuration is Mapped. I think when ever you use spring beans from code, an icon shows up to the left clicking on that takes you to bean definition in side the XML. And similarly when you scroll throw xml an icon appears in the left which will show usages of this bean in different classes. I am using IntelliJ Ultimate edition 14.

Comment: @pshirishreddy It seemed to work a bit patchily for me.  We had multiple application contexts for different testing setups though

Answer (score 12):

You need to check which configurations IntelliJ will use to provide inspections on wired beans.

Go to <kbd>File</kbd>➝<kbd>Project Structure</kbd>➝<kbd>Project Settings</kbd>➝<kbd>Modules</kbd>.

Select your module and selected (or add) the Spring facet.
In the right area you can add or modify application contexts that are used by your module. Just check every configuartion you need in your context.

Comment: while should I do it manually ? my colleagues do not have have the same problem. it is being preconfigure when they import the project. My question is what I did wrong for preventing being configured automatically

Comment: I don't know any other way then to do it manually. As far as I know it does not apply those changes automatically.

Comment: it is, you just have to accept to click on link saying "configure" when the project is being imported

Comment: Will keep that in mind the next time it's pops up :)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the above steps (in Bart's answer) , I had to

```
 1. click on the unmapped spring beans from the warning dialog box 
 2. select all the beans file
 3. set application context as "Spring Application Context" (You many want to change it to other contexts, if you need)
```

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to disable the notifications, just do this:

```
IntelliJ > Preferences > Notifications > Spring Configuration Check > No popup
```

Comment: Where can I find this setting for IntelliJ version 14 Ultimate?

Comment: It looks like for IntelliJ 14, Ultimate you can find it here:
Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Notifications | Spring Configuration Check

Comment: @atom88 This is still accurate as of IntelliJ Ultimate 2021.1

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with Gradle in Intellij, try the refresh ("Reload All Gradle Projects") button. It should make all of your Spring and other annotations recognizable by IDE, assuming you have properly defined your dependencies in *build.gradle* file.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add that for our project (idea 13), looking at <kbd>File</kbd> ➝ <kbd>Project Structure</kbd> ➝ <kbd>Project Settings</kbd> ➝ <kbd>Modules</kbd> (Spring) everything looked correct, but that then when you highlight all of them and click the edit pencil that is when we could truly see the ones that it is complaining about.  In our case they were all in our exploded war directory, so they only showed up after a full initial build.

Answer (score 2):

Same situation with my team, appeared that the "Import Maven project automatically" (Settings / Maven / Importing) is not checked on a fresh IntelliJ installation.

So check it and next time you'll import a Spring based project pom.xml file in "Maven projects" window, then a green window will appear up right and will wait for your validation to trigger the parsing of Spring configuration files detected.

Hope it helps!

EDIT : at this time, using JDK 1.7 instead of 1.8 + start from a extra-simple fresh "empty project" (IntelliJ) had seemed necessary too on a other colleague laptop

Answer (score 1):

Steps to follow

1. Go to File
2. Select Project Structure
3. From the left-hand side of Project Settings, select Modules.
4. Right-click on your project, select +Add, and select Spring
5. Application, Application Bootstrap, and Application MVC will be there

Answer (score 0):

Many answers or 6+ years old, so this is more current 2021-06 and while they are all still accurate AFAIK, the UI now gives a link to a help page that I'm including next.

When using IntelliJ Ultimate 2021.1 (probably applies to earlier releases), the `Show help` link sends you to this page: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2021.1/spring-support.html#spring-file-set

This page shows this image:
[image]

Which also says:

> If the Spring facet is configured correctly, you will see Spring gutter icons marking each component, bean, and so on.

Other answers also mentioned that if this isn't configured, everything still works (which was good for me to hear/read).